# Can I used a NES USB controller with XInput?

Tags: c++, directx, input

I'm doing a project to graduate from my game design degree and I have to recreate two levels from MegaMan(1987). 
I saw that there are usb nes controllers out there that are used for emulators on PC.  Before I purchase them and try out programming my game with them, I'd like to confirm that I can use them with Xinput.

If anyone knows if this is possible, please let me know!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

The specific controller itself has to support the XInput API, not the other way around. You'll need to see if the specific models you are interested in support the API, likely by reading the product specs or contacting the manufacturer.

If they don't (which seems likely), you'll need to use something else like DirectInput.